# Choice combobox based on input previous combobox

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, power-platform

```
    Or(
        DataCardValue28.Selected.Value = "Support",
        DataCardValue28.Selected.Value = "Development"
    ),
    Choices([@'Request Hardware'].Hardware),
Filter(Choices('Request Hardware'.Hardware); Value = "New MacBook Air 13.3 inch" || Value = "Windows Laptop EliteBook 14 inch (Finance Only)";
"Finance" = DataCardValue28.Selected.Value
 )
```

How do you ensure that when you choose suport of development in the previous option, that you are shown the entire list of data, and if you choose Finance, parts from the list?